# What is the difference if the function is monotone nondecreasing

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry, differential, differential-operators

I know that maybe is easy . But I depend on it to prove another theorems. I have this theorem :
Let 
$
{V}{\mathrm{,}}{W}\hspace{0.33em}\mathrm{\in}{C}^{1}\left[{\left[{{t}_{0}{\mathrm{,}}{t}_{0}\hspace{0.33em}\mathrm{{+}}{h}}\right]{\mathrm{,}}{R}}\right]
$

Be lower and upper solutions of the IVP:
$
{x}{\mathrm{'}}\mathrm{{=}}{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{,}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{;}}{x}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{=}}{x}_{0}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}{for}\hspace{0.33em}{t}\mathrm{\geq}{t}_{0}
$

$
{V}{\mathrm{'}}\mathrm{\leq}{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{,}}{V}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{;}}{V}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{x}_{0}\hspace{0.33em}\hspace{0.33em}{for}\hspace{0.33em}{t}\mathrm{\geq}{t}_{0}
$
$
{W}{\mathrm{'}}\mathrm{\geq}{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{,}}{W}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{;}}{W}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\geq}{x}_{0}\hspace{0.33em}{for}\hspace{0.33em}{t}\mathrm{\geq}{t}_{0}
$

Uncouppled  (natural type ) upper and lower solutions respectively . Suppose that for
$
{x}\mathrm{{>}}{y}
$
 satisfies the inequality 
$
{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{,}}{x}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{{-}}{f}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{L}{\mathrm{(}}{x}{\mathrm{,}}{y}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}{\mathrm{;}}{L}\mathrm{{>}}{0}
$
Then

$
{V}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{W}{\mathrm{(}}{t}_{0}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}
$
Implies that 
$
{V}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\mathrm{\leq}{W}{\mathrm{(}}{t}{\mathrm{)}}\hspace{0.33em}
$
$
{t}\mathrm{\in}\left[{{t}_{0}{\mathrm{,}}{t}_{0}\mathrm{{+}}{h}}\right]
$
I just want to ask if we add the assumption that the function
$
f\mathrm{(}t\mathrm{,}x\mathrm{)}
$
 is monotone nondecreasing in x .What is the difference ?? What is the difference in the proof ?? And what is the advantage ...?
Thanks in advance .....